# QDate::toString() and QDate::fromString() has different behavior in win10 and win7

Tags: qt

I found QDate::toString() has different behavior in win10 and win7. default QLocale(Chinese, Simplified Han, China).

```
qDebug() << QDate(2022,8,1).toString("MMM d yyyy");
```

output in win10/x64

```
"8月 1 2022"
```

output in win7/x64(VM of above pc)

```
"八月 1 2022"
```

fromString() has similar behavior

```
auto date1 = QDate().fromString("8月 1 2022", "MMM d yyyy"); // win10 ok, win7 fail
auto date2 = QDate().fromString("八月 1 2022", "MMM d yyyy"); // win10 fail, win7 ok
```

I have to parse string like "8月 1 2022" to QDate in win7, I tried "MMM d yyyy" and "MMMM d yyyy", both failed. Could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: My guess is that the cast from ascii is different due unicode, use QStringLiteral("...2022"), and see if this fixes it

Comment: Also i'd guess that you need locale aware conversion so QLocale::system().toDate(...) might also be what you need.

Comment: Not about the problem directly but: instead of `QDate().fromString` you should use `QDate::fromString` because it is static method and there is no need to create invalid instance of `QDate` first

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using the following function. The basic idea is to try decoding the string in different ways until it succeeds. This works on both win7 and win10. Thanks Daniel and artaxerx.

```
QDate parseDateTime(QString str)
{
    QDate date = QDate::fromString(str, Qt::ISODate);
    if(date.isValid())
        return date;

    date = QDate::fromString(str, "MMM d yyyy");
    if(date.isValid())
        return date;

    date = QDate::fromString(str, "MMMM d yyyy");
    if(date.isValid())
        return date;

    date = QLocale("zh_CN").toDate(str.simplified(), "MMM d yyyy");
    return date;
}
```